# jQuery Map V3 for jQuery Mobile using Search filter

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am fairly new to jquery mobile and I am in the process of creating a web app for a local store.  This local store have few branches and i wanted to implement google map where users can search the nearest branch by typing its postcode or street, google maps will then search the nearest location and display.  I have checked the API on this site:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/

but i can't seem to find what I want.

can anyone please advise or show me where to start?

many thanks.